# How to write Gson for this code?

Tags: java, android, json

In this code I'm parsing JSON and using `ArrayList` displaying it in a searchable spinner. The code works perfectly but when it comes to parse large JSON then it takes time and memory on mobile data.

Can any one suggest me a better idea to parse large JSON or can any one explain me how to parse it with Gson and loading into the searchable spinner?

```java
   try {
       if (response.has("products_data")) {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray();
               jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products_data");
            for (int t = 0; t < jsonArray.length(); t++) {
               object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(t);
               retailer_id = object.getString("retailer_id");
               retailer_name = object.getString("retailer_name");
               product_code = object.getString("product_code");
               product_name = object.getString("product_name");
               pro_packing = object.getString("pro_packing");
               pro_company=object.getString("pro_company");
               pro_generic_code=object.getString("pro_generic_code");
               pro_generic_name=object.getString("pro_generic_name");
               pro_stock = object.getInt("product_stock");
               product_MRP=object.getDouble("product_MRP");
               p = new Product();
               p.setRetailer_id(retailer_id);
               p.setRetailer_name(retailer_name);
               p.setProduct_code(product_code);
               p.setProduct_name(product_name);
               p.setPro_packing(pro_packing);
               p.setPro_company(pro_company);
               p.setPro_generic_code(pro_generic_code);
               p.setPro_generic_name(pro_generic_name);
               p.setPro_stock(pro_stock);
               p.setProduct_MRP(product_MRP);
               productlist.add(p);
               }
               progressDialog.dismiss();

         final List<String> pname = new ArrayList<String>();
         final List<String> pcode = new ArrayList<String>();
         pname.clear();
         pname.add(0,"Select Products");
         for (int i = 0; i < productlist.size(); i++) {
                                       pname.add(productlist.get(i).getProduct_name());
                                }
               // Creating adapter for spinner
         final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_spinnertxt, pname);

                                spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                public void run() {
                       // attaching data adapter to spinner

   autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                                        autoCompleteTextView.setSelection(0);
                                    }
                                });
                                     autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
          if(i>0) {
         p_id = productlist.get(i - 1).getProduct_code();
         p_stock = productlist.get(i - 1).getPro_stock();
         ppack = productlist.get(i - 1).getPro_packing();
         pcomp = productlist.get(i - 1).getPro_company();
         mrp = productlist.get(i - 1).getProduct_MRP();
         pseller = productlist.get(i - 1).getRetailer_name();
        // Log.i("pID:", p_id);
        //Log.i("pStock:", String.valueOf(p_stock));
         //Log.i("PMRP:", String.valueOf(mrp));
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }

                        }
```

This is my JSON Response:

```
"products_data": [
{
  "retailer_id": "mum0022",
  "retailer_name": "SAKTI MEDICO",
  "product_code": "6474",
  "product_name": "EPISOFT CLEANSING LOTION",
  "pro_packing": "125ML",
  "pro_company": "GLENMARK-GRACEWELLSPECIALITY",
  "pro_generic_code": "",
  "pro_generic_name": "",
  "product_stock": "7",
  "product_MRP": "209"
},
{
  "retailer_id": "mum0022",
  "retailer_name": "SAKTI MEDICO",
  "product_code": "8403",
  "product_name": "ELOVERA LOTION 150ML (BIG)",
  "pro_packing": "150ML",
  "pro_company": "GLENMARK (DERMAX)",
  "pro_generic_code": "",
  "pro_generic_name": "",
  "product_stock": "3",
  "product_MRP": "324.5"
},
...
```

Comment: post your json response as well

Comment: reference:
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-json-parsing-using-gson-and-recyclerview/

Comment: I am tempted to say: this site is not a free code writing service. But in any case: you want us to spend our time to help you fix your problem. So you could be at least so polite to properly format/indent all of your code. There is no need to push your code so far to the right that one needs to use horizontal scroll bars to look at it!

Comment: just go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ paste your json code, select json as source type and gson as annotation style.....there you go.....copy your gson code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Products_data implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("retailer_id")
private String retailer_id;

@SerializedName("retailer_name")
private String retailer_name;

@SerializedName("product_code")
private String product_code;

@SerializedName("product_name")
private String product_name;

@SerializedName("pro_packing")
private String pro_packing;

@SerializedName("pro_company")
private String pro_company;

@SerializedName("pro_generic_code")
private String pro_generic_code;

@SerializedName("pro_generic_name")
private String pro_generic_name;

@SerializedName("product_stock")
private Integer product_stock;

@SerializedName("product_MRP")
private Double product_MRP;


public Products_data() {
}

protected Products_data(Parcel in) {
    retailer_id = in.readString();
    retailer_name = in.readString();
    product_code = in.readString();
    product_name = in.readString();
    pro_packing = in.readString();
    pro_company = in.readString();
    pro_generic_code = in.readString();
    pro_generic_name = in.readString();
    product_stock = in.readInt();
    product_MRP = in.readDouble();
}

public static final Creator<Products_data> CREATOR = new Creator<Products_data>() {
    @Override
    public Products_data createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Products_data(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Products_data[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Products_data[size];
    }
};

public String getRetailer_id() {
    return retailer_id;
}

public void setRetailer_id(String retailer_id) {
    this.retailer_id = retailer_id;
}

public String getRetailer_name() {
    return retailer_name;
}

public void setRetailer_name(String retailer_name) {
    this.retailer_name = retailer_name;
}

public String getProduct_code() {
    return product_code;
}

public void setProduct_code(String product_code) {
    this.product_code = product_code;
}

public String getProduct_name() {
    return product_name;
}

public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
}

public String getPro_packing() {
    return pro_packing;
}

public void setPro_packing(String pro_packing) {
    this.pro_packing = pro_packing;
}

public String getPro_company() {
    return pro_company;
}

public void setPro_company(String pro_company) {
    this.pro_company = pro_company;
}

public String getPro_generic_code() {
    return pro_generic_code;
}

public void setPro_generic_code(String pro_generic_code) {
    this.pro_generic_code = pro_generic_code;
}

public String getPro_generic_name() {
    return pro_generic_name;
}

public void setPro_generic_name(String pro_generic_name) {
    this.pro_generic_name = pro_generic_name;
}

public Integer getProduct_stock() {
    return product_stock;
}

public void setProduct_stock(Integer product_stock) {
    this.product_stock = product_stock;
}

public Double getProduct_MRP() {
    return product_MRP;
}

public void setProduct_MRP(Double product_MRP) {
    this.product_MRP = product_MRP;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(retailer_id);
    parcel.writeString(retailer_name);
    parcel.writeString(product_code);
    parcel.writeString(product_name);
    parcel.writeString(pro_packing);
    parcel.writeString(pro_company);
    parcel.writeString(pro_generic_code);
    parcel.writeString(pro_generic_name);
    parcel.writeInt(product_stock);
    parcel.writeDouble(product_MRP);
}
}
```

After making this POJO class

```
gson.fromJson(json, Products_data.class);
```

Comment: Your most welcome if its work for you hit up :) thanks!

Comment: and how to load that into searchable spinner, like what i have done with json

Comment: you want just a spinner or searchable bar

Comment: spinner with searchable bar, i have done that with json in my previous coding and it's working fine but i don't know how to work on gson that' why

Comment: thank you so much @Nikhil bro, It's worked for me, Now it's working and loaded into searchable spinner, just i have to check it on mobile data